# How to limit the Login Attemps in PHP - Cookie Method or MySQL Method?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

I have a user registration system on my website and **I would like to limit the login attempts.** If someone inputs the wrong username/password **three times**, then it will **block their IP address** for a certain amount of time. I want to use a MySQL database with this. When I searched in internet, I've found some topics;

1. There are **Two (2) ways** to do this, One is **Cookies** and Second is **MySQL database itself**. So, what is **more secure** (because some says cookies are not reliable) and when to use (or not) cookie method or database method?
2. Most users have **dynamic IP address** and It will change when the user re-start the router. So, how we overcome this?
3. Any other method I should consider.

I don't have the slightest knowledge how to do this, so if someone could help me, it would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks.

Comment: Just log the IP and Time into your Database on each Attempt. If there are more than X Attempts, block the IP.

Comment: I suggest you to limit login attempts per user in database itself. For example i would add extra column to users info such as `LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` and if its more than 5 that's it! And you don't need to rely on cookies or worry about dynamic ip.

Comment: sorry, my suggestion is bad!@Bernhard came up with better idea!

Comment: @dehood Yes, very bad. That allows targeted DoS of user accounts by third parties…

Answer (score 1):

I also think about this and come up with the idea of creating `try_login_log` table, the column consist of:

- `log_id` (`INT`, `AUTO INCREMENT`)
- `user_id` (`VARCHAR`)
- `remote_address` (from `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`)
- `user_agent` (from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`)
- `result` (if failed then N or 0, if success then Y or 1)
- `time_stamp` (timestamp --> `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

then just do the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM try_login_log 
WHERE user_id = :user_id
      AND DATE(time_stamp) = CURDATE()
```

If the count result is 3 or more then just insert the IP Address to `banned_ip_list` table.

Well that's my idea, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

1. Because cookies are store on user computer so less secure.
2. I recommend using Mysql , you already have a function which validate the user credentials at login time , you can modified that function to check count of try and store/update **login_try_count(INT)** in mysql. now you have your count as store in mysql database , you can place condition based on mysql field login_try_count to retrict or block user.

Comment: Alright, let me try to unsuccessfully log into *your* account a couple of times… whoops, your account is now disabled. That's called a Denial of Service, and you're enabling it.

Comment: you are right ,  http://webcheatsheet.com/php/blocking_system_access.php , hope this helps you , one thing in my mind that Many schools , business , corporations all sit behind a common proxy/gateway, it means they share a very limited (perhaps even one) external IP addresses. In other words, if you block-out one user, you could be blocking an entire building.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to use session.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['wrong_password'])) {
    $_SESSION['wrong_password'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['wrong_password]++;
if($_SESSION['wrong_password'] > 3) {
    echo "Can't login anymore";
    exit();
}
```

The "block_state" will release when you attempt to log in on other computer or after 24 mins.
Thank you.

Comment: Any sane attacker would simply *not accept cookies* to circumvent this…

Comment: session, not cookie is stored in server. how attacker can handle this?

Comment: You need to learn how a session works. How does the server know which server-side stored session is associated with which user…? … … … Yes, cookies!